# tf.layers.batch_normalization parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I am not sure if it is only me who thinks that tensorflow documentation is a bit weak.

I was planing to use the tf.nn.batch_normalization function to implement batch normalization but later recognized the  tf.layers.batch_normalization function which seemingly should be the one to use for its simplicity. But the documentation is really poor if I may say it.

I am trying to understand how to *correctly* use it but with the information provided on the Web page is it really not easy. I am hoping that maybe some other people have experience and help me (and possibly many others) to understand it..

Let me share the interface first:

```
tf.layers.batch_normalization(
    inputs,
    axis=-1,
    momentum=0.99,
    epsilon=0.001,
    center=True,
    scale=True,
    beta_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
    gamma_initializer=tf.ones_initializer(),
    moving_mean_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
    moving_variance_initializer=tf.ones_initializer(),
    beta_regularizer=None,
    gamma_regularizer=None,
    beta_constraint=None,
    gamma_constraint=None,
    training=False,
    trainable=True,
    name=None,
    reuse=None,
    renorm=False,
    renorm_clipping=None,
    renorm_momentum=0.99,
    fused=None,
    virtual_batch_size=None,
    adjustment=None
)
```

Q1) beta values are initialized to zero and gamma values are initialized to 1. But it does not say why. When batch normalization used, I understand that the ordinary bias parameter of the neural network becomes obsolete and beta parameter in the batch normalization step kind of does the same thing. From that angle, setting beta to zero is understandable. But why are gamma values initialized to 1? Is that really the most efficient way?

Q2) I see a momentum parameter there as well. The documentation just says " Momentum for the moving average.". I assume that this parameter is used when calculating the "mean" value for a certain mini batch in the corresponding hidden layer. With other words, the mean value used in batch normalization is NOT the mean of current mini batch, it is rather primarily the mean of the last 100 mini batches (since momentum = 0.99). But it is very unclear how this parameter affects the execution in testing, or if I am just validating my model on the dev set by calculating cost and accuracy. My *assumption* is that anytime I deal with test and dev sets, I set the parameter "training" to False so that momentum parameter becomes obsolete for that particular execution and the "mean" and "variance" values that were calculated during the training are used now instead of calculating new mean and variance values. It is how it should be if I am mistaken but I do not see anything in the documentation if it is the case. Could anyone confirm that my understanding correct? If not, I would really appreciate further explanation on this.

Q3) I am having difficulties to give a meaning to the trainable parameter. I assume beta and gamma params are meant here. Why would they not be trainable?

Q4) The "reuse" parameter. What is it really?

Q5) adjustment parameter. Another mistery..

Q5) A kind of summary question.. Here is my overall assumption that needs confirmation and feedback.. Important params here are:
- inputs
- axis
- momentum
- center
- scale
- training
And I assume that as long as the training=True when training, we are safe. And as long as training=False when validating dev set or test set or even when using the model in real life, we are safe too.

Any feedback will really be appreciated.

ADDENDUM:

Confusion continues. Help!

I am trying to use this function instead of implementing a batch normalizer manually. I have the following forward propagation function that loops through layers of the NN.

```
def forward_propagation_with_relu(X, num_units_in_layers, parameters, 
                                  normalize_batch, training, mb_size=7):

    L = len(num_units_in_layers)

    A_temp = tf.transpose(X)

    for i in range (1, L):
        W = parameters.get("W"+str(i))
        b = parameters.get("b"+str(i))
        Z_temp = tf.add(tf.matmul(W, A_temp), b)

        if normalize_batch:
            if (i < (L-1)):  
                with tf.variable_scope("batch_norm_scope", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
                    Z_temp = tf.layers.batch_normalization(Z_temp, axis=-1, 
                                                           training=training)

        A_temp = tf.nn.relu(Z_temp)

    return Z_temp   #This is the linear output of last layer
```

The tf.layers.batch_normalization(..) function wants to have static dimensions but I do not have it in my case.

Since I apply mini batches rather than training the entire train set each time before I run the optimizer, 1 dimension of the X appears to be unknown.

If I write:

```
print(X.shape)
```

I get:

```
(?, 5)
```

And when this is the case, when I run the whole program I get the following error below.

I saw in some other threads that some people say that they could solve the problem by using tf.reshape function. I try it.. Forward prop goes fine but later on it crashes in the Adam Optimizer..

Here is what I get when I run the code above (without using tf.reshape):

How do I solve this???

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-191-990fb7d7f7f6> in <module>()
     24 parameters = nn_model(train_input_paths, dev_input_paths, test_input_paths, learning_rate, num_train_epochs,
     25                       normalize_batch, epoch_period_to_save_cost, minibatch_size, num_units_in_layers,
---> 26                       lambd, print_progress)
     27 
     28 print(parameters)

<ipython-input-190-59594e979129> in nn_model(train_input_paths, dev_input_paths, test_input_paths, learning_rate, num_train_epochs, normalize_batch, epoch_period_to_save_cost, minibatch_size, num_units_in_layers, lambd, print_progress)
     34         # Forward propagation: Build the forward propagation in the tensorflow graph
     35         ZL = forward_propagation_with_relu(X_mini_batch, num_units_in_layers, 
---> 36                                            parameters, normalize_batch, training)
     37 
     38     with tf.name_scope("calc_cost"):

<ipython-input-187-8012e2fb6236> in forward_propagation_with_relu(X, num_units_in_layers, parameters, normalize_batch, training, mb_size)
     15                 with tf.variable_scope("batch_norm_scope", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
     16                     Z_temp = tf.layers.batch_normalization(Z_temp, axis=-1, 
---> 17                                                            training=training)
     18 
     19         A_temp = tf.nn.relu(Z_temp)

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/normalization.py in batch_normalization(inputs, axis, momentum, epsilon, center, scale, beta_initializer, gamma_initializer, moving_mean_initializer, moving_variance_initializer, beta_regularizer, gamma_regularizer, beta_constraint, gamma_constraint, training, trainable, name, reuse, renorm, renorm_clipping, renorm_momentum, fused, virtual_batch_size, adjustment)
    775       _reuse=reuse,
    776       _scope=name)
--> 777   return layer.apply(inputs, training=training)
    778 
    779 

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py in apply(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    805       Output tensor(s).
    806     """
--> 807     return self.__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    808 
    809   def _add_inbound_node(self,

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    676           self._defer_regularizers = True
    677           with ops.init_scope():
--> 678             self.build(input_shapes)
    679           # Create any regularizers added by `build`.
    680           self._maybe_create_variable_regularizers()

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/normalization.py in build(self, input_shape)
    251       if axis_to_dim[x] is None:
    252         raise ValueError('Input has undefined `axis` dimension. Input shape: ',
--> 253                          input_shape)
    254     self.input_spec = base.InputSpec(ndim=ndims, axes=axis_to_dim)
    255 

ValueError: ('Input has undefined `axis` dimension. Input shape: ', TensorShape([Dimension(6), Dimension(None)]))
```

This is so hopeless..

ADDENDUM(2)

I am adding more information:

The following simply means that there are 5 units in input layer, 6 units in each hidden layer, and 2 units in output layer.

```
num_units_in_layers = [5,6,6,2]
```

Here is the updated version of forward prop function with tf.reshape

```
def forward_propagation_with_relu(X, num_units_in_layers, parameters, 
                                  normalize_batch, training, mb_size=7):

    L = len(num_units_in_layers)
    print("X.shape before reshape: ", X.shape)             # ADDED LINE 1
    X = tf.reshape(X, [mb_size, num_units_in_layers[0]])   # ADDED LINE 2
    print("X.shape after reshape: ", X.shape)              # ADDED LINE 3
    A_temp = tf.transpose(X)

    for i in range (1, L):
        W = parameters.get("W"+str(i))
        b = parameters.get("b"+str(i))
        Z_temp = tf.add(tf.matmul(W, A_temp), b)

        if normalize_batch:
            if (i < (L-1)):  
                with tf.variable_scope("batch_norm_scope", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
                    Z_temp = tf.layers.batch_normalization(Z_temp, axis=-1, 
                                                           training=training)

        A_temp = tf.nn.relu(Z_temp)

    return Z_temp   #This is the linear output of last layer
```

When I do this, I can run the forward prop function. But it seems to be crashing in later execution. Here is the error that I get. (Note that I print out the shape of input X before and after reshaping in the forward prop function).

```
X.shape before reshape:  (?, 5)
X.shape after reshape:  (7, 5)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1349     try:
-> 1350       return fn(*args)
   1351     except errors.OpError as e:

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1328                                    feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1329                                    status, run_metadata)
   1330 

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    515             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 516             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    517     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [7] vs. [2]
     [[Node: forward_prop/batch_norm_scope/batch_normalization/cond_2/AssignMovingAvg/sub = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@batch_norm_scope/batch_normalization/moving_mean"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](forward_prop/batch_norm_scope/batch_normalization/cond_2/Switch_1:1, forward_prop/batch_norm_scope/batch_normalization/cond_2/AssignMovingAvg/sub/Switch_1:1)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-222-990fb7d7f7f6> in <module>()
     24 parameters = nn_model(train_input_paths, dev_input_paths, test_input_paths, learning_rate, num_train_epochs,
     25                       normalize_batch, epoch_period_to_save_cost, minibatch_size, num_units_in_layers,
---> 26                       lambd, print_progress)
     27 
     28 print(parameters)

<ipython-input-221-59594e979129> in nn_model(train_input_paths, dev_input_paths, test_input_paths, learning_rate, num_train_epochs, normalize_batch, epoch_period_to_save_cost, minibatch_size, num_units_in_layers, lambd, print_progress)
     88                                                                         cost_mini_batch,
     89                                                                         accuracy_mini_batch],
---> 90                                                                         feed_dict={training: True})
     91                       nr_of_minibatches += 1
     92                       sum_minibatch_costs += minibatch_cost

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    893     try:
    894       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 895                          run_metadata_ptr)
    896       if run_metadata:
    897         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1126     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1127       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1128                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1129     else:
   1130       results = []

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1342     if handle is None:
   1343       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feeds, fetches, targets,
-> 1344                            options, run_metadata)
   1345     else:
   1346       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feeds, fetches)

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1361         except KeyError:
   1362           pass
-> 1363       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1364 
   1365   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [7] vs. [2]
     [[Node: forward_prop/batch_norm_scope/batch_normalization/cond_2/AssignMovingAvg/sub = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@batch_norm_scope/batch_normalization/moving_mean"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](forward_prop/batch_norm_scope/batch_normalization/cond_2/Switch_1:1, forward_prop/batch_norm_scope/batch_normalization/cond_2/AssignMovingAvg/sub/Switch_1:1)]]

Caused by op 'forward_prop/batch_norm_scope/batch_normalization/cond_2/AssignMovingAvg/sub', defined at:
  File "/home/cesncn/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/cesncn/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/cesncn/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/home/cesncn/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/home/cesncn/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 478, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "/home/cesncn/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/home/cesncn/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/home/cesncn/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cesncn/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/home/cesncn/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/home/cesncn/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cesncn/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cesncn/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/home/cesncn/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/home/cesncn/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/home/cesncn/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/home/cesncn/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cesncn/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2728, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/home/cesncn/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2850, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/home/cesncn/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-222-990fb7d7f7f6>", line 26, in <module>
    lambd, print_progress)
  File "<ipython-input-221-59594e979129>", line 36, in nn_model
    parameters, normalize_batch, training)
  File "<ipython-input-218-62e4c6126c2c>", line 19, in forward_propagation_with_relu
    training=training)
  File "/home/cesncn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/normalization.py", line 777, in batch_normalization
    return layer.apply(inputs, training=training)
  File "/home/cesncn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 807, in apply
    return self.__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cesncn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 697, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cesncn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/normalization.py", line 602, in call
    lambda: self.moving_mean)
  File "/home/cesncn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/utils.py", line 211, in smart_cond
    return control_flow_ops.cond(pred, true_fn=fn1, false_fn=fn2, name=name)
  File "/home/cesncn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 316, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cesncn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1985, in cond
    orig_res_t, res_t = context_t.BuildCondBranch(true_fn)
  File "/home/cesncn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1839, in BuildCondBranch
    original_result = fn()
  File "/home/cesncn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/normalization.py", line 601, in <lambda>
    lambda: _do_update(self.moving_mean, new_mean),
  File "/home/cesncn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/normalization.py", line 597, in _do_update
    var, value, self.momentum, zero_debias=False)
  File "/home/cesncn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/moving_averages.py", line 87, in assign_moving_average
    update_delta = (variable - value) * decay
  File "/home/cesncn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 778, in _run_op
    return getattr(ops.Tensor, operator)(a._AsTensor(), *args)
  File "/home/cesncn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 934, in binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
  File "/home/cesncn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 4819, in _sub
    "Sub", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/home/cesncn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/cesncn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3267, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/cesncn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1650, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [7] vs. [2]
     [[Node: forward_prop/batch_norm_scope/batch_normalization/cond_2/AssignMovingAvg/sub = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@batch_norm_scope/batch_normalization/moving_mean"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](forward_prop/batch_norm_scope/batch_normalization/cond_2/Switch_1:1, forward_prop/batch_norm_scope/batch_normalization/cond_2/AssignMovingAvg/sub/Switch_1:1)]]
```

Regarding the question why the shape of X is not static.. I don't know...
HEre is how I setup the dataset.

```
with tf.name_scope("next_train_batch"):
    filenames = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[None])
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
    dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda filename: tf.data.TextLineDataset(filename).skip(1).map(decode_csv))
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
    dataset = dataset.batch(minibatch_size)
    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    X_mini_batch, Y_mini_batch = iterator.get_next()
```

I have 2 csv files that include the train data.

```
train_path1 = "train1.csv"
train_path2 = "train2.csv"
train_input_paths = [train_path1, train_path2]
```

And I use the initializable iterator as following:

```
sess.run(iterator.initializer, 
         feed_dict={filenames: train_input_paths})
```

During the training, I keep getting mini batches from the train set. Everything works fine when I disable batch normalization. If I enable batch norm, it requires static shape of the input X (mini batch). I reshape it but this time it crashes later in the execution as seen above.

ADDENDUM(3)

I guess I figured out where it crashes. It probably crashes when I run the optimizer after calculating the cost.

First the sequence of commands:
First forward prop, then compute cost, then run optimizer. First 2 seems to be working but not the optimizer.

HEre is how I define the optimizer:

```
with tf.name_scope("train"):
    update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):        
        # Backpropagation: Define the tensorflow optimizer. Use an AdamOptimizer.
        optimizer =  tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(cost_mini_batch)
```

I have the update_ops there to be able to update the moving averages. If I interpret it right, it is just crashing when it tries to update moving averages. I might be misinterpreting the error msg as well..

ADDENDUM(4)

I tried to normalize based on the known dimension and it worked! But that's not the dimension I would like to normalize, which is now confusing. Let me elaborate:

nr of units in input layer: 5
nr of units in layer 1 (first hidden layer): 6
so weight1 is (6, 5) matrix
Assume that mini batch size is 7.
Shape of A[0] (or X_mini_batch) in my case is: (7, 5), where 7 is the # training samples in mini batch, and 5 is the # units in input layer.

When calculating Z[1]...
Z[1] = weight1 * A[0].transpose
... then shape of Z[1] is (6, 7) matrix, where each column gives 6 features for each train sample.

The question is then which column do we want to normalize in Z[1]? What makes sense to me is that you normalize each feature from all given train samples. This means that I need to normalize each row bcz I have different feature values for different train examples in each row. And since Z[1] has the shape (6, 7), if I set axis=0, it should refer to normalization in each row. And 7 is the unknown number in my case so it doesn't hurt. Based on this logic, it works! But I am totally puzzled if axis=0 really refers to each row here... Let me show another example about this axis issue, which has bothered me for a long time now..

The *irrelevant from this topic* code example:

```
cc = tf.constant([[1.,2.,3.], 
                  [4.,5.,6.]])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf.reduce_mean(cc, axis=0)))
    print(sess.run(tf.reduce_mean(cc, axis=1)))
```

This gives the following output:

```
[2.5 3.5 4.5]
[2. 5.]
```

When I set axis to 0, it is giving the average of each column. And if axis=1, it is giving the average of each row.

(Note that cc.shape gives (2,3))

Now the million dollar question: In a 2 dimensional matrix, is axis 0 or 1 when I want to address each row?

ADDENDUM(5)
I guess I get it now correctly. Let me summarize my axis understanding here. Hopefully I am getting it right now...

Here is the Z[1] matrix representation with the shape (6,7):

t_ex :   train example
f:       feature

```
t_ex1   t_ex2   t_ex3   t_ex4   t_ex5   t_ex6   t_ex7
  f1      f1      f1      f1      f1      f1      f1
  f2      f2      f2      f2      f2      f2      f2
  f3      f3      f3      f3      f3      f3      f3
  f4      f4      f4      f4      f4      f4      f4
  f5      f5      f5      f5      f5      f5      f5
  f6      f6      f6      f6      f6      f6      f6
```

In this mini batch above, there are 7 train examples and each train ex has 6 features (since there are 6 units in layer 1). When we say "tf.layers.batch_normalization(..,axis=0)", we mean that the normalization has to be done per row for each feature to eliminate the high variance between - say - f1 values in the first row.

With other words, we do NOT normalize f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6 with each other. We normalize f1:s with each other, and f2:s with each other, and so on..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q1) Initializing gamma as 1, beta as 0 means directly using the normalized inputs. Since there is no prior information about what the variance of a layer output should be, it is fair enough to assume standard Gaussian.

Q2) During training phase (`training=True`), the batch is normalized with their own mean and var, assuming that training data are randomly sampled. During test (`training=False`), since the test data could be arbitrarily sampled, we cannot use their mean and var. Thus, we use, as you said, the moving averaging estimations from the last "100" training iterations.

Q3) Yes, trainable refers to `beta` and `gamma`. There are cases to set `trainable=False`, e.g. if a novel method is used to update the parameters, or if the batch_norm layer is pre-trained and needs to be frozen.

Q4) You may have noticed `reuse` parameters in other `tf.layers` functions as well. In general, if you wanna call a layer more than once (e.g. training and validation) and you do not wanna TensorFlow to think that you are creating a new layer, you set `reuse=True`. I prefer `with tf.variable_scope(..., reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):` to achieve the same purpose.

Q5) I am not sure about this one. I guess it is for users who want to design new tricks to adjust the scale and bias.

Q6) Yes, you are right.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!I further investigated and here comes some more comments. First, moving avg is calculated during training but if I got it right are moving averages NOT updated in the function. The user has to do it manually, which is a big drawback of the function. Second, I actually never could make it work when I tried to set the any reuse param to sth in any function. But it works if I go for "with tf.variable_scope(...)" option. Do you know why? And third, seemingly the given batch has to have a fixed size when calling the function. Otherwise not working. Do you know why?

Comment: I added more information about the problem (look under the text ADDENDUM above). Anyone who can have further insights??

Comment: @edn First, moving averages are added to `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` that needs to be run either using control dependence or by collecting them into an op (using `tf.get_collection`) and running that op. I don't consider it a big drawback because it is just one extra code line anyway. Second, please try setting `reuse=False` in the first run and `reuse=True` when calling it again. Third, tbh, I have not tried batch_norm with a dynamic shape. Would you plz explain why in the error the TensorShape is [6, None], and also post the error with using `tf.reshape`?

Comment: A workaround is to use `tf.nn.batch_normalization` using moments calculated yourself (according to solutions provided in [this thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/139))

Comment: Thank you again for your reply. I added more information above. Please see the info under ADDENDUM(2) above. I can also try to set reuse to False first then to True. But I don't know though how I will do it in the above code. Any hints..?
I implemented a manual solution by using tf.nn.batch_normalization but I would like to use tf.layers. because it looks simpler wrt automatic tracking of moving averages of mean and variance. And it is more secure in the sense that it should be more bug-free

Comment: And I added even more info now under ADDENDUM(3) above.

Comment: Strangely, I tried using `tf.data` to get `x_batch` with shape [None, 3, 64, 64], passing it directly as `xn = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x_batch, axis=1, training=True)` and `mu, var = tf.nn.moments(xn, axes=[0, 2, 3])`, and obatined the correct result of roughly [0, 0, 0] and [1, 1, 1] with no errors. This worked for both `make_initializable_iterator()` and `make_one_shot_iterator()`. Thus, I think batch_norm can handle None shape? I am using TensorFlow 1.5.

Comment: I am thankful! I am using 1.6 version. I don't know though if it matters in this case. 2 questions: Did you try to normalize based on the last dimension? Did you run the optimizer as well afterwards?

Comment: Btw: If you have any chance to try, can you try to normalize it for a shape [7, ?] and axis=-1? (7 is just an example. It can be any number.) I believe the problem in my case is that I try to normalize based on the unknown dimension. In your example, (if I read it right) you are normalizing based on a known dimension. axis=1 and the dimension value is 3.

Comment: Nice point. I tried all you've mentioned. Among them, normalization on the `None` dimension did not work. However, it worked if i do `x_batch.set_shape([64, 3, 64, 64])`, i.e. annotating the shape of the tensor. Please check if you could do this in your code.

Comment: Now I have ADDENDUM(4) above. I wonder if I was normalizing on the "correct" axis. What is really meant by axis is another mistery for me.. We are so close to solving this. :)

Comment: In batch_norm, the axis should always be the feature/channel dimension (so `axis=0` in your case). You could easily verify this by checking if the mean in the batch dimension is 0 after normalization.

Comment: Yes, I believe I need to normalize based on axis=0. But did you check the example in ADDENDUM(4) above? In that exmaple, axis=0 refers to columns, which is extremely confusing.

Comment: Yes, I did... well, `reduce_sum(x, axis=0)` means summing up each row, thus resulting in a column vector; `reduce_mean` is just `reduce_sum` divided by N; `batch_norm(x, axis=0)` means normalizing each row. You said "When I set the axis to 0, it is giving the average of each column", it is literally wrong; it is giving the average of rows/each row.

Comment: I added ADDENDUM(5) above to clarify things. Seemingly I was misinterpreting the axis parameter here.. Do you think you can confirm that the description is correct now?
@Richard_wth, your help has been really invaluable here. Very highly appreciated. Thank you very much!